# Вывод вещественных чисел в Windows API

Tags: windows, ассемблер

Я задался целью написать на ассемблере калькулятор алгебраических выражений.
Все получилось, правильно считает, но не получается вывести ответ. Если ввести 2+3, то он выдаст -993709916 или какой-то другой бред.

Вот код, который выводит ответ

```
format  db      '%d', 0
zero    db      0
buf     db      128 dup(?)
chread  dq      0
num     dq      ?
result  dq      ?
mov result, rax
mov rcx, offset buf
mov rdx, offset format
mov r8, offset result
call wsprintfA
mov rcx, output
mov rdx, offset buf
mov r8, 10h
mov r9, offset num
push 0
call WriteConsole
```

А вот весь остальной

```
include includes\win64.inc
include includes\user32.inc
includelib includes\user32.lib
include includes\kernel32.inc
includelib includes\kernel32.lib

extern wsprintfA:near

.data
input   dq      ?
output  dq      ?
format  db      '%d', 0
zero    db      0
buf     db      128 dup(?)
chread  dq      0
num     dq      ?
result  dq      ?
.code
Main proc 
    mov rcx, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov input, rax
    mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov output, rax
minput:
    mov rcx, input
    mov rdx, offset buf
    mov r8, 127
    mov r9, offset chread
    push 0
    call ReadConsole
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov rdx, offset zero
    add rdx, chread
    dec rdx
    dec rdx
    call Calc
    mov result, rax
    mov rcx, offset buf
    mov rdx, offset format
    mov r8, offset result
    call wsprintfA
    mov rcx, output
    mov rdx, offset buf
    mov r8, 10h
    mov r9, offset num
    push 0
    call WriteConsole
    jmp minput
exit:
    call ExitProcess
Main endp

Calc proc
    mov rbp, rsp
    finit
    xor rax, rax
    push 0
    push 0
cstart:
    mov al, [rdx]
    cmp al, '0'
    jl mnext1
    cmp al, '9'
    jle mnum

mnext1:
    cmp al, ')'
    je mclbr

    cmp al, '+'
    je madd
    cmp al, '('
    je mobr
    test al, al
    jz madd

    cmp al, 'a'
    jl mnext2
    cmp al, 'z'
    jle mfunc

mnext2:
    cmp al, ','
    je mcomma

    cmp al, '-'
    je mneg

    cmp al, '*'
    je mmul

    cmp al, '/'
    je mdiv
    jmp mend
mnum:
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov byte ptr [num], 10
    fild word ptr [num]
    fldz
nstart:
    sub al, '0'
    mov byte ptr [num], al
    fild word ptr [num]

    faddp st(1), st
    fdiv st, st(1)

    inc ecx

    dec rdx
    mov al, [rdx]
    cmp al, '.'
    jne nnext1
    xor ecx, ecx
    dec rdx
    mov al, [rdx]
nnext1:
    cmp al, '0'
    jl nend
    cmp al, '9'
    jle nstart

nend:
    fmul
    dec ecx 
    jnz nend
    sub rsp, 8
    fstp qword ptr[rsp]
mmul1:
    bt bx, 0
    jnc mend
    fld qword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8
    fmul qword ptr[rsp]
    fstp qword ptr[rsp]
    btr rbx, 0
    jmp mend
mclbr:
    shl rbx, 1
    push 0
    dec rdx
    jmp mend
mobr:
    shr rbx, 1
madd:
    fld qword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8
    fadd qword ptr[rsp]
    fstp qword ptr[rsp]
    dec rdx
    jmp mend

mfunc:
    shl rax, 8
    dec rdx 
    mov al, [rdx]
    cmp al, 'a'
    jl fcmp
    cmp al, 'z'
    jle mfunc
fcmp:
    fld qword ptr [rsp]
    shr rax, 8
    cmp eax, 'trqs'     ;sqrt
    je sqrt
    cmp eax, 006E6973h  ;sin
    je sin
    cmp eax, 00736F63h  ;cos
    je cos
    cmp eax, 006E6174h  ;tan
    je tan
    cmp eax, 'nata'     ;atan
    je atan
    cmp eax, 00776F70h  ;pow
    je pow
    push 1
    call ExitProcess
sqrt:
    fsqrt
    fst qword ptr [rsp]
    jmp mmul1
sin:
    fsin
    fst qword ptr [rsp]
    jmp mmul1
cos:
    fcos
    fst qword ptr [rsp]
    jmp mmul1
tan:
    fptan
    fst qword ptr [rsp]
    jmp mmul1
atan:
    fpatan
    fst qword ptr [rsp]
    jmp mmul1
pow:
    fld1
    add rsp, 8
    fld qword ptr [rsp]
    fistp qword ptr [rsp]
    mov ecx, [rsp]
powmul:
    ;fmul st, st(1)
    fmul
    test ecx, ecx
    jz mret
    dec ecx
    jmp powmul
mret:
    jmp mmul1

mcomma:
    fld qword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8
    fadd qword ptr[rsp]
    fstp qword ptr[rsp]
    push 0
    dec rdx
    jmp mend
mneg:
    ;pop r10
    ;btc r10, 63
    ;push r10
    btc word ptr [rax+7], 7
    jmp madd
mdiv:
    fld1 
    fdiv qword ptr [rsp]
    fst qword ptr [rsp]
mmul:
    btc rbx, 0
    dec rdx
mend:
    test al, al
    jnz cstart
mret1:

    ;fld qword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8
    fadd qword ptr[rsp]
    fstp qword ptr[rsp]

    fld qword ptr [rsp]
    pop rax
    mov rsp, rbp
    ret
Calc endp

end
```

Comment: Для вывода вещественных чисел нужно использовать %f вместо %d

Comment: @insolor в документации к этой функции написано, что нужно использовать %d или %i. %f не работает, в ответ на 2+3 выводит f 3

Comment: Посмотрел описание функции, похоже wsprintf вообще не поддерживает формат с плавающей точкой. Попробуйте swprintf и %f.

Comment: @insolor это не Win api функция, на асме ее не вызовешь. Придется ручками конвертировать.

Comment: Можно попробовать msvcrt.dll подключить, скорее всего там она есть

Comment: Спасибо, нашел там printf и оно ожило.